# Server requests only possible when running with nodemon/babel-node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, babeljs, nodemon

I have a backend application running with node.js. I have some functions to make some requests, and the work fine when running on nodemon/babel-node (`npm run dev`), but when I run `npm start`, I can't make GET or POST requests. This started happening when I changed the mysql connection from one database to another (I'm using mysql2).

When I try to make a request through my browser and postman, I get the following message (with `npm start`):

[image]

[image]

With `npm run dev` I get the full json response with all users from the database. Now, here's my code:

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "babel src -d dist",
    "dev": "nodemon src --exec babel-node", //<-- These are the commands for npm run dev
    "start": "node dist" //<-- npm start
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "mysql2": "^2.3.3",
    "swagger-jsdoc": "^6.2.1",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^4.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.17.10",
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.2",
    "@babel/node": "^7.17.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.16"
  }
}
```

index.js:

```
import app from "./app";

app.listen(3000, '192.168.6.180');
console.log('Server on port 3000');
```

app.js:

```
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import morgan from 'morgan';

import swaggerJSDoc from 'swagger-jsdoc';
import swaggerUI from 'swagger-ui-express';
import { options } from './swaggerOptions';
const specs = swaggerJSDoc(options);

import tasksRoutes from './routes/tasks';

const app = express();//This is my app using express, which will listen to the port 3000

app.use(cors());
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(express.json());

app.use(tasksRoutes);

app.use('/docs', swaggerUI.serve, swaggerUI.setup(specs));

export default app;
```

controllers/tasks.js:

```
import {connect} from '../database';

//This one connects to the new database and doesn't work with npm start
export const getUsers = async (req, res) => {
    console.log('first');
    const connection = await connect();
    const[rows] = await connection.query('SELECT * FROM usuarios');
    res.json(rows);
};


//This connects to the test database and works just fine
export const getTasks = async (req, res) => {
    const connection = await connect();
    const[rows] = await connection.query('SELECT * FROM tasks');
    res.json(rows);
};
```

routes/tasks.js

```
import { Router } from 'express';
import { getTasks, getUsers } from '../controllers/tasks';

const router = Router();

//Doesn't work
router.get('/users', getUsers);

//Works
router.get('/tasks', getTasks);

export default router;
```

Comment: What exactly does "I can't make GET or POST requests" mean? How exactly do they fail? Do you get error messages? etc

Comment: @ChrisG Oops, I forgot to share one screenshot. On my browser and postman I get `Cannot GET /users`

Comment: At the end of tasks.js it should say `export default router;` so I'm wondering how this works at all...

Comment: @ChrisG Yeah, you're right again. Edited the post again.

Comment: I guess I found it: `console.log(first)` creates an unknown reference error and will crash the program. Didn't you check your server-side console after the request?

Comment: @ChrisG I used that console log to print some variable to see if the program actually entered the function and print the log (it did not). I just changed it to a string. The server-side console only shows `GET /users 404 4.844 ms - 144`. I guess it can't even find the function when using `npm start`.